# Rustのコンパイルエラー（no method named `map` found for type ...）の原因

Tags: rust

ソート済みのTSVを読み込んで、keys番目の列を使って重複行を判定し、重複を除いて残った行だけを出力する予定のrustプログラムです（`uniq`コマンドと似た動作をするはずです）。
コンパイルエラーの原因がわかりません。

```rust
use std::io;
use itertools::Itertools;


fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut reader = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .delimiter(b'\t')
        .has_headers(false)
        .trim(csv::Trim::All)
        .from_reader(stdin);

    let keys = vec![1, 2];

    // case 1 コンパイルできない
    reader.records()
        .map(|r| {
            (keys.iter().map(|&k| r.expect("row").iter().collect::<Vec<&str>>()[k]).collect::<Vec<_>>(), r)
        })
        .dedup_by(|x, y| x.0 == y.0)
        .map(|(key, value)| value)
        .for_each(|x| println!("{:?}", x));

    // case 2 動く
    reader.records()
        .map(|r| r.expect("row"))
        .dedup_by(|x, y| {
            keys.iter().map(|&k| x.get(k).unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>() == keys.iter().map(|&k| y.get(k).unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>()
        })
        .for_each(|x| println!("{:?}", x));
}
```

プログラム中のコメントにあるcase 2のほうは予想通りに動きます。case 1も同じ動作をすると思ったのですが、コンパイルができず、以下のエラーが出ます。

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling dedupnande v0.1.0 (/home/xxxx/code/rust/dedupnande)
error[E0599]: no method named `map` found for type `itertools::adaptors::DedupBy<std::iter::Map<csv::reader::StringRecordsIter<'_, std::io::Stdin>, [closure@src/main.rs:17:14: 19:10 keys:_]>, [closure@src/main.rs:20:19: 20:36]>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:21:10
   |
21 |         .map(|(key, value)| value)
   |          ^^^ method not found in `itertools::adaptors::DedupBy<std::iter::Map<csv::reader::StringRecordsIter<'_, std::io::Stdin>, [closure@src/main.rs:17:14: 19:10 keys:_]>, [closure@src/main.rs:20:19: 20:36]>`
   |
   = note: the method `map` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `&mut itertools::adaptors::DedupBy<std::iter::Map<csv::reader::StringRecordsIter<'_, std::io::Stdin>, [closure@src/main.rs:17:14: 19:10 keys:_]>, [closure@src/main.rs:20:19: 20:36]> : std::iter::Iterator`
           `itertools::adaptors::DedupBy<std::iter::Map<csv::reader::StringRecordsIter<'_, std::io::Stdin>, [closure@src/main.rs:17:14: 19:10 keys:_]>, [closure@src/main.rs:20:19: 20:36]> : std::iter::Iterator`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `dedupnande`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

`map`が`&mut DedupBy<...>`にしか実装されていないというエラーみたいですが、意味がわかりません。DedupBy構造体はIteratorトレイトを実装しているんじゃないんですか……？

実行環境：

```
[package]
(...)
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
csv = "1.1"
itertools = "0.8.2"
```

```
$ cargo --version
cargo 1.40.0 (bc8e4c8be 2019-11-22)
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.40.0 (73528e339 2019-12-16)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

こんにちは。

ちょっとこれは罠ですね。 `DedupBy` は `Iterator` トレイトを実装していますが、条件付きです。
ベースとなるイテレータのアイテムが `PartialEq` を実装しているときのみです。

https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.2/itertools/structs/struct.DedupBy.html#impl-Iterator

そして `reader.records()` のアイテムは `Result<StringRecord, Error>` [なのです](https://docs.rs/csv/1.1.2/csv/struct.StringRecordsIter.html#impl-Iterator)が、これは `Error` が `PartialEq` を実装していないため `PartialEq` ではありません。

https://docs.rs/csv/1.1.2/csv/struct.Error.html

なので下記のようにcase 1でも `Result::expect` を呼んで `Error` を持たないように変形してあげればコンパイルが通るようになります。

```rust
    reader
        .records()
        .map(|r| {
            // rのResultを剥がしておく
            let r = r.expect("row");
            (
                keys.iter()
                    .map(|&k| r.iter().collect::<Vec<&str>>()[k].to_string())
                    .collect::<Vec<_>>(),
                r,
            )
        })
        .dedup_by(|x, y| x.0 == y.0)
        .map(|(_, value)| value)
        .for_each(|x| println!("{:?}", x));
```

Comment: なるほど、エラーが読めていませんでした。よくわかりました。さりげなく足されている`.to_string()`も助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 余談ですが、 `dedup_by` は本来は `PartialEq` を必要としないのでイテレータになるために `PartialEq` を必要とするのは過剰な要求です。itertoolsにPRを送って修正してもらったので将来リリースされるバージョンでは提示されているcase 1のコードもコンパイルが通るようになるかと思います。
https://github.com/rust-itertools/itertools/pull/397#issuecomment-574408715